# Did Gimli get a new axe?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

In the movie Gimli breaks his axe when he tries to destroy the Ring. Did he use another axe after that or did he reforge the axe (which sounds implausible considering the amount of damage it took)?

Comment: Just a note that all questions about LOTR, Hobbit, Silm, etc. need the [[tag:tolkiens-legendarium]] tag on them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many axes did Gimli bring on the quest of the Fellowship?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89433/how-many-axes-did-gimli-bring-on-the-quest-of-the-fellowship) (at the very least, it's very much related)

Comment: @NathanS Looks very much like a duplicate to me, the top answers all address this scene and his axes.

Answer (score -4):

He's a dwarf, they craft these things for a living. 
In the books, Gimli uses only One axe. He just carries a broad bladed ax. In the films to showcase dwarven craft and esoteric designs of it's equipment, Gimli fielded a multitude of axes. His first one was destroyed in an attempt to destroy the ring. Two throwing axes, one of which was destroyed in an attempt to attack whom he thought was Saruman (Gandalf). and his signature double bladed ax.